# Grouping Data by categoryId with JSONata

Tags: arrays, json, jsonata

### The challenge arises when some entries have multiple categoryIds, resulting in difficulties in proper grouping

I was able to group the data with the **'$distinct'** method, but some of the data has more than one categoryId, which causes problems in grouping. How can I group categoryIds that are an array?

**JSONata: https://try.jsonata.org/79QRdDXs9**

Comment: i have same issue

Answer (score 1):

You should create on map for categoryId as key and object of data as value.

Comment: I did it here, but the data comes as an array, how do I know which index value belongs to that category? https://try.jsonata.org/SJTpjUojd